# Generate an auth cookie from webapi for use within web application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have managed to get the bearer token working within an api project.

Within my solution I have 2 projects an api and mvc application. The api handles authentication and generation of the bearer token.

I want to call the api from the mvc application to authenticate and to be able to set auth cookies for use with the mvc application.

My web application has none of the standard account controller actions. I have removed all actions and only have the single action as below. My api should take care of everything.

Short question is how.

I have created an action within my mvc application to call the /token endpoint within the api application.

```
    public class BearerToken
    {
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(".issued")]
    public DateTime Issued { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(".expires")]
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}

  public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"grant_type", "password"},
            {"username", login.UserName},
            {"password", login.Password}
        };
        var data = RestSharperHelper.PostForm(parameters, "http://localhost:2000/Token");
        var bearer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BearerToken>(data);
            if (bearer != null)
            {
              //user access_token for all future api requests

              //how do I generate the local auth cookie to tell the application User.Authenticated = true? 


            }
```

After I have called the /Token endpoint how do I set the local auth cookie to allow the webapp to use the [Authorize] attribute on my controllers?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the bearer token from the web api, you can do the following

//Decrypt the token (this requires using the same machine key on the servers where web api and wep app reside)

```
var unencryptedToken = Startup.OAuthBearerOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect(accessToken);
```

//Extract the claims identity from the token

```
var identity = unencryptedToken.Identity;
```

//Create the claims identity for the application cookie (this is what the web app will be using)

```
var id = new ClaimsIdentity(identity.Claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

// Sign in to the web app with the new claims identity using OWIN AuthenticationManager. This will create the application cookie and correctly populate User.IsAuthenticated() and ClaimsIdentity on the HttpContext, after which your attribute based authentication will work

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(id);
```

Note: I couldn't get from the original question how close to the oauth specs you need to adhere to or if your web app is internet facing or enterprise. One can claim that web app should not be able to decrypt the token if this is 100% oauth implementation (or why give web app a change to decrypt and potentially modify the claims in the token). My response is that it all depends on your application and security needs. If you need to use the bearer token somehow within the web app, you have to decrypt the token and extract the claims. As long as your your web app does not try to append to claims and re-encrypt, I don't see a problem with doing this. In addition, you can also include an extra field within your payload only web api can read which includes the hash of the token as it was created. This serves as an anti-tempering mechanism. If the claims in the token changes, the hash signature would be different.

Another note: You will need to sync this logic with the bearer token expiration logic. Everytime you renew your bearer token, you will also repeat the above procedure. (Refresh the claims identity within the web app) But it is few extra lines of code and it works.